# TCP program to reverse a string in C language giving half result

Tags: c, string, tcp

i have written a TCP client/server program to reverse a string however the result is coming partially right.

**Client:**

```
#‎include‬<stdio.h>
#include<sys/socket.h>
#include<netinet/in.h>
#include<sys/types.h>
void main()
{ 
   struct sockaddr_in server;
   int sock;
   char buffer[20];

   printf("Enter a string :");
   scanf("%s",buffer);

   server.sin_family = AF_INET;
   server.sin_port = 2000;
   server.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("127.0.0.1");
   sock = socket(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM, 0);

   connect(sock, (struct sockaddr*) &server, sizeof(server));
   send(sock, buffer, sizeof(buffer), 0);
   recv(sock, buffer, sizeof(buffer), 0);

   printf("The reverse string is: %s",buffer);
   printf("\n");
}
```

**SERVER:**

```
‪#‎include‬<stdio.h>
#include<sys/socket.h>
#include<netinet/in.h>
#include<sys/types.h>
#include<string.h>
void main()
{ 
   struct sockaddr_in server, client;
   char buffer[20], temp;
   int n, sock, newsock, i, j;

   sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
   server.sin_family = AF_INET;
   server.sin_port = 2000;
   server.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("127.0.0.1");
   bind(sock, (struct sockaddr*) &server, sizeof(server));

   listen(sock, 2);
   n = sizeof(client);
   new sock = accept(sock, (struct sockaddr*) &client, &n);
   for(;;)
   {
      recv(newsock, buffer, sizeof(buffer), 0);
      i = 0; 
      j = strlen(buffer) - 1;
      while(i<j)
      { 
         temp = buffer[i]; 
         buffer[i] = buffer[j]; 
         buffer[j] = temp; 
         i++; 
         j--;
       }
   send(newsock, buffer, sizeof(buffer), 0);
   }
}
```

**Now when i run it and suppose i input the string as "hello how are you" but the result is coming as only "olleh" and skipping rest of the sentence. am i missing something here?**

Comment: Well, it is skipping the rest of the sentence *first* and then giving the "olleh" suffix of the reversal. :)

Comment: that is why i have included while(i<j) so it will stop when it reaches exactly half of the string :P

Comment: Your server is stuck in an infinite loop after accepting one client. After that client disconnects, it will call recv and send again and again on the same socket, which is no longer any good

Comment: yes you're right...i will remove the for(;;). i only tested once so didnot notice it. also i changed scanf() to fgets(). now getting the correct result. thanks for help :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your problem starts early on, in the `scanf` function, as `%s` reads until the first whitespace (which is right after "hello"). You need to read until the end of the line ([`getline`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/getline) can do that for you).

Comment: This worked! Damn i totally overlooked the basics. getline() and fgets() both works!

Answer (score 1):

Your client only "receives" once.  You are not guaranteed to get the entire message back in one packet so you need to either receive until you get as many bytes as you sent, or implement some other way of recognizing the end of the message.
In the client, Change:

```
 recv(sock,buffer,sizeof(buffer),0);
```

To something like:

```
while (you haven't gotten the entire packet)
{
    recv(sock,buffer,sizeof(buffer),0);
    //append buffer to another buffer
}
```